# Joining of 5 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I need to join 5 tables to get particular bill number.

Tables are

1. bill,
2. Service_bill
3. Damage_cost
4. Extraperson_cost
5. Advance_cost

Except `bill`, all other tables are may store null values.

My query is like below...

```
select   bill.bill_no,
         bill.total,
         bill.discount,
         bill.to_be_paid,
         isnull(Service_bill.total_amt,0) as ServiceCharge,
         isnull(Damage_cost.total_amt,0) as DamageCost,
         isnull(Extraperson_cost.total_amt,0) as ExtraCost,
         isnull(Advance_cost.total_amount,0) as Advance 
from     bill 
left join Advance_cost       on bill.bill_no=Advance_cost.room_bill_no and bill.bill_no='57' 
inner join Service_bill      on bill.bill_no=Service_bill.room_bill_no 
inner join Damage_cost       on bill.bill_no=Damage_cost.room_bill_no 
inner join Extraperson_cost  on bill.bill_no=Extraperson_cost.room_bill_no
```

Now it returns data's, which joins conditions are getting true.

First table should have values then other tables are `null` only so it must be return first tables completely. But i don't know why it comes like this!

Comment: Could not understand what you mean by "first table should have values then other tables are null only so it must be return first tables completely. but i dont know why it comes like this????"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Neville k... i got it using outer join...

```
select bill.bill_no,bill.total,bill.discount,bill.to_be_paid,
       isnull(Service_bill.total_amt,0) as ServiceCharge,
       isnull(Damage_cost.total_amt,0) as DamageCost,
       isnull(Extraperson_cost.total_amt,0) as ExtraCost,
       isnull(Advance_cost.total_amount,0) as Advance 
from   bill 
left join Advance_cost           on bill.bill_no=Advance_cost.room_bill_no 
left outer join Service_bill     on bill.bill_no=Service_bill.room_bill_no 
left outer join Damage_cost      on bill.bill_no=Damage_cost.room_bill_no 
left outer join Extraperson_cost on bill.bill_no=Extraperson_cost.room_bill_no
where  bill.bill_no='57'
```

Answer (score 2):

The inner joins mean that you are only finding bills for people who have records in all 4 other tables. Use outer joins instead.

Also, you are limiting the results to those items where there is a record in "advance_cost" for bill 57. That's probaly not the idea...